# Pandas dataframe efficient find and replace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

I'm working on a Pandas dataframe that has about **20 million rows** and **30 columns**.

What I would like to do, for each column of this dataframe, is somehow iterate over rows, such that:

- if the element is among the 5 most frequent ones of its column, then leave it as it is
- if it is not, then replace it with the string 'Other'.

I feel like as I basically have to iterate over each element (and I have 60 million of them), it is going to take quite some time anyway.
However, I don't know what the best approach is here.

What I have tried sofar, with df being my dataframe:

```
df_columns = df.columns.tolist()

top_five = [df[col].value_counts(sort=True).index.tolist()[0:5] for col in df_columns]

L=[[] for i in range(len(df_columns))]
for i, col in (enumerate(df_columns)):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if df[col][j] not in top_five[i]:
            L[i].append(df[col][j])
    df[col] = df[col].replace(L[i], 'Other')
```

Maybe **df.loc** or **numpy.where** would be more suitable for this purpose?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over rows is not recommended. You should always try to use a vectorized method when possible. In this case you can do this:

1. Find the 5 most frequent values and store in an array
2. Replace values

```
for col in df.columns:
    top_five = df[col].value_counts(ascending=False).iloc[0:5].index #Find most frequent values
    df.loc[~df[col].isin(top_five),col] = 'Other'   #Boolean indexing to find the rows with those values, and replacing value by 'Other'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that uses `rank`.  First, create a test data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['h'] * 4 + ['i'] * 3 + ['j'] * 2 + ['k'],
     'y': ['d'] * 4 + ['e'] * 3 + ['f'] * 2 + ['g'],
     'z': ['a'] * 4 + ['b'] * 3 + ['c'] * 2 + ['d'],
    })

print(df.tail())
   x  y  z
5  i  e  b
6  i  e  b
7  j  f  c
8  j  f  c
9  k  g  d
```

Now use rank to get the frequency of each value; filter to find rank less than the threshold (rank=1 is the most common), change NAs to 'other'.  Also, I converted to the Categorical type.  This will probably save a lot of space.

```
mask = df.rank(method='dense').lt(3) # change 3 to 5 to get 5 most common
df_new = df[mask].fillna('other').astype('category')
print(df_new)

       x      y      z
0      h      d      a
1      h      d      a
2      h      d      a
3      h      d      a
4      i      e      b
5      i      e      b
6      i      e      b
7  other  other  other
8  other  other  other
9  other  other  other
```

references on Categorical:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html#use-efficient-datatypes